# Jquery button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

How can we do some action in JQuery when a button in a template is clicked by the cursor. The template will have a button element.

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#buttonID', function() {
   // Code to execute after click
});

Comment: @KaneCohen This is an answer, post it...

Comment: @MetalFrog, i thought it was just too short to justify a full blown answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally use [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event:

```
$("#buttonID").click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Or using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (JQuery v1.7 and up):

```
$("#buttonID").on("click", function() {
    // do something
});
```

---

If your template is a string or JQuery object then try this before applying template:

```
$("#buttonID", template).click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read carefully the section about "Direct and delegated events" from http://api.jquery.com/on/. It explains something that can have a LARGE impact the performance of your web page, in some situations.

With that in mind, it is generally safest to do things this way:

```
$("some selector").on("click", "itemtag", function(event){
    // Do something (may include figuring out which element was clicked)
});
```